# How to harden/prevent ESD in a circuit?

Tags: led, integrated-circuit, esd

I've designed a simple circuit with three LEDs in series with a matching resistor, all powered by an IC. [image] I want to make my circuit less susceptible to electrostatic discharge since it will be deployed in an exposed area. I've read that I need to add a capacitor, and perhaps a resistor in parallel but I don't understand where to put these components. If anyone has any advice or resource I could look into, I would love to hear about possible solutions. What components should I add to my circuit to prevent ESD?

Comment: A reverse diode may be used to protect  the string or one for each LED is each are exposed..

Comment: What do you mean by "exposed area"? Will people be touching the wiring?

Comment: add 0.1uF in parallel with each LED. thus no matter what node is touched, the charge cannot cause large instantaneous voltage spikes.

Answer (score 1):

ESD protection is needed if the design comes in contact with objects that have high  voltage potentials (like humans). If you think people will be touching the LED's or the cable, then protect the circuit. I'm not sure that LED's are susceptible to ESD damage as other parts. At any rate, if your worried about it a TVS diode across the power terminals would do the trick.

Comment: I think you would just want to protect the IC. I've never heard of LEDs being damaged by ESD from someone touching them?

Comment: You should know that LED's are extremely susceptible to -ve ESD with a Vr rating of -5V max unless they have internal protection added. This vulnerability exists when they are inactive.

Comment: I've never had an LED fail from ESD, I have had transistors and IC's fail. My manufacturing division has poor ESD standards